# Mobile Wifi Rental in Turkey?

Tags: budget, airports, planning, turkey, istanbul

I was in Japan last summer and rented a pocket wifi device that provides 4G mobile internet. It made my trip much more easier. Now, I will be in Turkey on January and was wondering if there is any service like it.
Any ideas??

Comment: A simple google search revealed some results: [1](https://www.tepwireless.com/wifi/turkey), [2](https://www.rentnconnect.com/)

Comment: Tep seems to ship from UK and the other's website looks like not up to date. The last review on the site is on March. That's why I was asking for real experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 weeks ago I had a guest who stayed in one of my airbnb apartments for 8 days. Before coming here, she told me that she was expecting a package from a company called [Alldaywifi](https://alldaywifi.com). When I checked their website, I found out that they provide unlimited wifi which can be connected by 10 different devices and the rental fee per day is $5.

Although I have WiFi in my apartment, this dongle is for those who need mobile internet outside of hotel/airbnb. Also they have some additional services such as transportation card, museum tickets, and airport transfer. I was surprised that I havent heard about Alldaywifi before. After a little research I noticed there are [other companies](http://rent-wifi.com/pocket-wifi-in-turkey/) doing the same thing in Turkey.

My guest gave me the kit when she checked out and told me that they will come to get the device back. She also told me that she has a 10% discount code that can be used for 3 times within 6 months.

So, if anyone here plans to visit Turkey and rent an Alldaywifi unit, you can use her code 00ee8fc2

Answer (score 4):

If i remember correctly, there are small USB bundle modems for mobile internet. Proper to use for laptop. I looked for some websites but couldn't find information English. The companies are:

- Turkcell: This company is the best in my opinion, they're giving faster internet than others do. And i guess their cellular coverage area is also the largest. It can be a bit pricy.
- Vodafone
- Avea: this company is the cheapest option. It will be fine if you will stay  in city centers.

Average price for the USB bundle is 40$.And i guess you will have to pay for the amount of internet that you use. I am not sure about if they are offering pre-paid options, or you have to make a contract. You will have to ask. There are stores of these brands in every 2-3 streets, so it won't be hard to find.

Enjoy the trip. Cheers!

Comment: But these dongles need to be connected to the computers via USB and not useful for my tablet or iphone.

Comment: yes these dongles were for pc/laptop. I discovered that for tablets or smartphones there are wifi hotspot modems. Something like this:

http://www.turkcell.com.tr/cihazlar/vinn-ailesi/vinn-wifi-mf65m?place=device_category

Probably other companies also have such modems. But cannot find any info in english. You will have to ask in the store.